# MPI_Waitall() behavior given MPI_Request array with possibly uninitialized slots for asynchronous send/recv

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I have come across a scenario in which I need to allocate a static array of type MPI_Request for keeping track of asynchronous send and receive MPI operations. I have total of 8 Isend and Irecv operations - where 4 of which are Isend and the remaining is Irecv. However, I do not call these 8 functions all at once. Depending on the incoming data, these functions are called in pairs, which means I may call pair of 1 send/receive or 2 send/receive or 3 send/receive or all at once. The fact that they are going to be called in pairs is certain but how many of them will be called is not certain. Below is a pseudo-code:

```
MPI_Request reqs[8];
MPI_Status stats[8];

if (Rank A exists){
    //The process have to send data to A and receive data from A
    MPI_Isend(A, ..., &reqs[0]);
    MPI_Irecv(A, ..., &reqs[1]);
}
if(Rank B exists){
    //The process have to send data to B and receive data from B
    MPI_Isend(B, ..., &reqs[2]);
    MPI_Irecv(B, ..., &reqs[3]);
}
if(Rank C exists){
    //The process have to send data to C and receive data from C
    MPI_Isend(C, ..., &reqs[4]);
    MPI_Irecv(C, ..., &reqs[5]);
}
if(Rank D exists){
    //The process have to send data to D and receive data from D
    MPI_Isend(D, ..., &reqs[6]);
    MPI_Irecv(D, ..., &reqs[7]);
}
//Wait for asynchronous operations to complete
MPI_Waitall(8, reqs, stats);
```

Now, I am not sure what the behavior of the program will be. There are total of 8 distinct asynchronous send and receive function calls and there is one slot for each function in `MPI_reqs[8]` for each call but not all of the functions will always be used. When some of them are not called, some slots in `MPI_reqs[8]` will be uninitialized. However, I need `MPI_Waitall(8, reqs, stats)` to return regardless of whether all slots in `MPI_reqs[8]` are initialized or not.

Could someone explain how the program might behave in this particular scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set / initialize those missing requests with `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`. That said, why not just

```
int count = 0;
...
Isend(A, &reqs[count++]);
...
MPI_Waitall(count, reqs, stats);
```

Of course, leaving the value uninitialized and feeding it to some function that reads from it is not a good idea.

Comment: Even though I use count, how would I know what length the reqs array should have?

Comment: you obviously need to initialize `count=0`. once you performed all your isend/irecv, `reqs` will have its first `count` requests initialized. I know this is pseudo code, but keep in mind the MPI semantic is `MPI_ISend(..., &reqs[count++])` or `MPI_Isend(..., reqs + count++)`

Comment: Sure I understand how count works. I define length of the MPI_Request array to be 8 since there are total of 8 distinct non-block function calls. And then I initialize the array to all `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`. After all I receive something I think to be a deadlock and the execution does not proceed further. I also tried replacing `MPI_Irecv()` with blocking `MPI_recv()`, in that scenerio `MPI_Waitall()` threw an error.

Comment: @nmd_07 you will have to ask a follow-up question containing an [mcve] to discuss the deadlock or error issue.

Comment: @nmd_07, the point is that although need to preemptively reserve memory for all 8 `MPI_Request` objects, `count` tracks how many of them you actually use at runtime.

For example, if only one of your `if` statements above evaluates to true, then the post-increments in `&reqs[count++]` mean  `count == 2` when you reach the end and `MPI_Waitall(count, reqs, stats);` results in waiting for the first two request objects in `reqs` (and the first two status objects in `stats` being updated).